# What library contains file X?

Tags: linux, libraries, find

I'm tired of looking for specific files for specific problems, for questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28597/where-can-i-install-termcap-from) for example.

Now, is there a way for someone to find out by himself what library one should install to have some file?

Conditions:

- you have the name of the file you want to make available
- you don't know the name of the library
- the library is (of course) not installed on your system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Debian or Ubuntu, you can ask your package manager about installed packages

```
dpkg --search <filename>
```

If the package isn't installed, you can use `apt-file`

```
apt-file update
apt-file search <filename>
```

If you don't know anything about the specific file you're looking for, but you want to know about some specific functionalty (mentioned in the package description)

```
apt-cache search <keywords>
```

To search for a package when you know part of the name (even if the package is not installed)

```
dpkg -l '*pattern*'
```

Comment: Dear Ken, this sounds promising. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, because the search `apt-file search ncurses` shows me 1489 files. I think I need to gather the correct file from the set manually, no? Thanks.

Comment: @Dr Beco: I think for that, you want `dpkg -l '*ncurses*'` (which I just added to the answer).

Comment: Thanks. Very detailed and helpful. If I could, I would +1 it more than once. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Query your package manager.

```
yum whatprovides '*/somefile'
```